# Flutter - Add a page to a loaded PDF document gives LateInitializationError

Tags: flutter, pdf

Using https://pub.dev/packages/pdf plugin, I was trying to add a page to a bytes loaded asset PDF document.

```
await pw.Document.load(Parser(
 (await rootBundle.load('assets/original.pdf')).buffer.asUint8List()
)).addPage(await pw.Page(
 pageFormat : PdfPageFormat.a4,
 build : (pw.Context context) => pw.Text('...')
));

class Parser implements PdfDocumentParserBase{

  @override
  Uint8List bytes;

  Parser(this.bytes);

  @override
  void mergeDocument(PdfDocument doc){}

  @override
  int get size => bytes.length;

  @override
  int get xrefOffset => 0;

  @override
  PdfVersion get version => PdfVersion.pdf_1_4;
}
```

It gave me this.

> LateInitializationError: Field 'catalog' has not been initialized.
>
> PdfDocument.catalog (package:pdf/src/pdf/document.dart)
> PdfDocument.pdfPageList (package:pdf/src/pdf/document.dart:133:34)
> new PdfPage (package:pdf/src/pdf/obj/page.dart:65:19)
> Page.generate (package:pdf/src/widgets/page.dart:111:18)
> Document.addPage (package:pdf/src/widgets/document.dart:117:10)
> ViewState.create (package:blablabla/pdfer.dart:257:9)

There is no such error if I start from an empty document `pw.Document()`

Annoyingly, the plugin dev team provides nothing about that parser thing.